# How to remove all getters and setters from an object in Javascript and keep pure value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects, setter, getter

I'm using a library called which takes a JS object as an input. Unfortunately, the JSONP api that I am using returns an object containing getters and setters, which this particular library does not know how to handle.

How can I remove all getters and setters from an object while retaining the values of the properties, so I have a Plain Old JavaScript Object?

Comment: Can you share some example ?

Comment: How does the JSONP look like? JSON can't contain any getters or setters.

Comment: `JSON.stringify(myobj)`

Comment: ok, my JS object has getters and setters. Maybe I can serialize to JSON and back.

Here's an example, it's a library called Rivets that is causing the issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/w23uLttu/2/

Comment: That JS Fiddle seems to be working fine.

Comment: @Gothdo it should bind to the changes in the value - notice the header does not update when the text box changes.

Comment: @PatrickScott I don't see any JSONP in that fiddle

Comment: @Gothdo JSONP has nothing to do with it. The question is how to remove all getters and setters from a JS object and retain the values.

Comment: See without the getters and setters: http://jsfiddle.net/w23uLttu/5/

Comment: @Gothdo JSONP is not JSON. It's essentially JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a solution for this special case/environment/setting might look like that ...

```
var
  obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(model));

console.log("obj before : ", obj);

Object.keys(obj).reduce(function (obj, key) {

  if (obj["_" +  key] === obj[key]) {
    delete obj["_" +  key];
  }
  return obj;

}, obj);

console.log("obj after : ", obj);
```

see also ... http://jsfiddle.net/w23uLttu/8/

Comment: yea in this particular case, however the _ may not always be used

Comment: @PatrickScott - in case stored values get encapsulated correctly one still gets the handling of getters/setters for free via `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(model));`.

Comment: Instead of using `delete`, you'd better pass a callback to `parse` or `stringify`

Comment: @Bergi - you are right ("know your spec") - `stringify` was the right place for omitting the pseudo private keys.

Answer (score 0):

Use `getOwnPropertyDescriptors` to get all the current descriptors, find those with `get` property, and redefine them. However, you will only be able to do this if the property is configurable.

```
const descriptors = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(obj);

Object.keys(descriptors)
  .filter(key => descriptors[key].get)
  .forEach(key => Object.defineProperty(obj, key, {value: obj[key]}));
```

`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors` is an ES7 proposal. Meanwhile, here's an implementation from [here](http://www.2ality.com/2016/02/object-getownpropertydescriptors.html):

```
function getOwnPropertyDescriptors(obj) {
  const result = {};
  for (let key of Reflect.ownKeys(obj)) {
      result[key] = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, key);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Like the idea, ```getOwnPropertyDescriptors``` isn't a function though, it's actually ```getOwnPropertyDescriptor```, so might have to switch this to get keys first, and get the descriptor for each?

Comment: looks like that is proposed, however not available yet (coming in es2017/es8) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptors

Answer (score 0):

After trying all sorts of things such as serializing to JSON and back, I ended up writing a simple shallowClone function to handle this:

```
const shallowClone = (obj) => {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((clone, key) => {
    clone[key] = obj[key];
    return clone;
  }, {});
}
```

Comment: still not super happy with this answer though

Comment: ... http://jsfiddle.net/w23uLttu/9/ ... but your approach won't remove the pseudo private notation of e.g. `_name` vs `name` with both are referring to the same value ... `{_name: "Hear me?", name: "Hear me?"}` - with your given example one does already achieve the same result via `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(model))`. A valid/final solution should take into account those duplicates.

Comment: yea exactly, maybe something like this combined with getOwnPropertyDescriptor

Comment: how about having a look onto http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39875871/how-to-remove-all-getters-and-setters-from-an-object-in-javascript-and-keep-pure/39877447#39877447

Comment: @PatrickLeeScott did you ever come up with something you like better?