# How to filter out getters and setters when console logging Vuejs data?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, console.log

I am writing a vue js app.

When I console log the data from the vue instance I see it with it's getters and setters which are not relevant to me.

```
var vm = new vue({

  data () { return { testData: { stuff: 'some stuff' } }; },

  methods: {
    log () {
      console.log( this.testData );
    }
  }
})
```

You can see the above example [here](http://jsbin.com/xezovo).

This is what I get in the console (very dirty):

[image]

I can [remove the setters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39875871/how-to-remove-all-getters-and-setters-from-an-object-in-javascript-and-keep-pure) before logging but that seems to be overkill for a simple log.

Vue used to have a built in [`$log`](http://v1.vuejs.org/api/#vm-log) method for this purpose, but it has been removed in v2.

Does anyone have any idea how to filter the data from the getters/setters before logging?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of the following should do the trick:

```
log: function(d) {
    console.log(Object.assign({}, this.form));
}

// if you have jQuery
log: function(d) {
    console.log($.extend({}, this.form));
}

// what $log does
log: function(d) {
    console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.form))); 
}

// ES6 Destructuring
log: d => ({ ...d })
```

Comment: Third one works though if you have functions as values (methods), it will not be shown. Sample https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YYzKPv

Answer (score 4):

You may do that:

`console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.testData)));`

```js
new Vue({
   el:"#app",
 data:{
 testData: { 
           stuff: 'some stuff',
           something: 'some thing'
 }
 },
 methods:{
 log(){     
           console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.testData)));
 }
 }
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    <button v-on:click="log">log</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I marked the other answer since it had more options. But, thanks!